# query to display subdocument not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm fairly new to mongoose and I am trying to write a query that just returns a subdocument within my main document.

My document structure is like this:

```
PROFILE
    - CONTACTS [ARRAY]
```

I've written the following endpoint to return one contact, where I pass the profile id and the id of the subdocument:

"/:owerId/getcontact/:contactId"

My Express function code looks like this:

```
router.route('/:ownerId/getcontact/:contactId')

    .get(function(req, res){
      Profile.findOne({'owner_id':req.params.ownerId}).then(function(err, profile){
        if(err)
          res.send(err);

        profile.findOne({'_id':req.params.contactId}).then(function(err, contact){
          if(err)
            res.send(err);
          res.json(contact);
        })

      })
    })
```

But this code returns the whole profile.

When I try to get by ID it does the same thing. Here is my code and just below that is the entire profile that is returned:

```
router.route('/:ownerId/getcontact/:contactId')

.get(function(req, res){
  Profile.findById(req.params.ownerId).then(function(err, profile){
    if(err)
      res.send(err);

      var data = profile.contacts.id(req.params.contactId);

    res.json(data);

  })
})





{
  "_id": "5886e3692ca4542c453431ee",
  "initial": "u",
  "last_name": "randal",
  "first_name": "chris",
  "owner_id": "5886e32c2ca4542c453431ed",
  "__v": 1,
  "contacts": [
    {
      "last_name": "Eltoro",
      "first_name": "Peter",
      "_id": "5886e3f5a219472cac886a9f",
      "businesses": [],
      "addresses": [],
      "phones": [
        {
          "phone_type": "mobile",
          "phone_number": "555-555-999",
          "_id": "5886e3f5a219472cac886aa2"
        },
        {
          "phone_type": "home",
          "phone_number": "999-876-000",
          "_id": "5886e3f5a219472cac886aa1"
        }
      ],
      "emails": [
        {
          "email_address": "tim@time.com",
          "_id": "5886e3f5a219472cac886aa0"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "college": "University of WA",
      "highschool": "Kalaheo",
      "birthday": "1990-12-22T08:00:00.000Z",
      "last_name": "Smith",
      "first_name": "Suzanne",
      "_id": "5886fb7fac288c2e31eabe0a",
      "businesses": [],
      "addresses": [
        {
          "zip": "98777",
          "state": "WA",
          "city": "Seattle",
          "address_2": "Apt 234",
          "address": "124 194th St. SW",
          "_id": "5886fb7fac288c2e31eabe0e"
        }
      ],
      "phones": [
        {
          "phone_type": "mobile",
          "phone_number": "206-899-9898",
          "_id": "5886fb7fac288c2e31eabe0d"
        },
        {
          "phone_type": "home",
          "phone_number": "206-789-0987",
          "_id": "5886fb7fac288c2e31eabe0c"
        }
      ],
      "emails": [
        {
          "email_type": "personal",
          "email_address": "suzanne@smith.com",
          "_id": "5886fb7fac288c2e31eabe0b"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "last_name": "Alabaster",
      "first_name": "Cindy",
      "_id": "5888b0bd3c025e54476828d9",
      "businesses": [],
      "addresses": [],
      "phones": [
        {
          "phone_type": "home",
          "phone_number": "999-999-0909",
          "_id": "5888b0bd3c025e54476828dc"
        },
        {
          "phone_type": "home",
          "phone_number": "000-000-0000",
          "_id": "5888b0bd3c025e54476828db"
        }
      ],
      "emails": [
        {
          "email_address": "Some@them.com",
          "_id": "5888b0bd3c025e54476828da"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "businesses": [],
  "addresses": [],
  "phones": [
    {
      "phone_number": "999-999-9999",
      "phone_type": "mobile",
      "_id": "5886e37f2ca4542c453431ef"
    }
  ],
  "emails": []
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongoose sub documents have special methods to retrieve them:

```
router
  .route('/:ownerId/getcontact/:contactId')
    .get(function(req, res) {
      Profile.findOne({ owner_id: req.params.ownerId }, function(err, profile) {
        if ( err ) {
          res.send(err);
        }
        var contact = profile.contacts.id(req.params.contactId);
        res.json(contact);
      });
    });
```

See [Mongoose Sub Documents](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html).

Comment: It's because your profiles `_id` is different from `owner_id` so you should'nt use `findById` you should use `findOne`. answer updated.

Comment: I changed the ownerId param to contain the _id. I just didn't change the param name. So it actually is looking up the profile by the _id. I've tried findOne and findById and for some reason, I still get the entire record back, not just the subdocument. Strange.

Comment: check your routes maybe there is some route which overrides this one.

Answer (score 0):

Another route is through the aggregation framework where you can use the **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)**, **[`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/#exp._S_arrayElemAt)** and **[`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#exp._S_filter)** operators to return the data you want.

Consider running the following aggregate operation in your API endpoint implementation:

```
router.route('/:ownerId/getcontact/:contactId')
    .get(function(req, res){
        var ownerId = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId(req.params.ownerId),
            contactId = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId(req.params.contactId);

        Profile.aggregate([
            { "$match": { "owner_id": ownerId } },
            {
                "$project": {
                    "contact": {
                        "$arrayElemAt": [
                            { 
                                "$filter": {
                                    "input": "$contacts",
                                    "as": "contact",
                                    "cond": { "$eq": ["$$contact._id", contactId] }
                                }
                            },
                            0
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        ]).exec(function(err, profile){
            if(err) res.send(err);          
            res.json(profile[0].contact);
        })
    })
```